# Flutter Keyboard padding not working after I upgraded to Flutter 3.10. How to prevent BottomSheet from being overlapped by keyboard in Flutter 3.10?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom to determine padding according to Keyboard size. after upgrading to Flutter 3.10 now the bottomsheet is overlapped by the keyboard!

```dart
void onTotalsButtonPressed() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        child: AddProduct(
          items: Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).searchItems,
          type: OrderTypes.sales,
        ),
      ),
      isScrollControlled: true,
    );
  }
```

When I build the app with Flutter 3.7.12 on my other machine it works well and padding is determined dynamically according to keyboard state!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the same issue.

If you are using ScreenUtil, you will have to use v5.8.1 and set `useInheritedMediaQuery` to `true`

Comment: Thanks man, I have been cracking my head since this morning on this, worked perfectly fine

Comment: Thanks Deeply man :D That's definitely the culprit.